# Unexpected list behaviour on append in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, append

I am solving this question on  [Interviewbit](https://www.interviewbit.com)  :

*Given a set of distinct integers, S, return all possible subsets.Elements in a subset must be in non-descending order.The solution set must not contain duplicate sub sets.*

And here is my *simple*, *self explanatory* code :

```
ans_list=[]

def solve(i,a,tmp,l,k):
    global ans_list
    if i==l :
      print "List to append:     " ,tmp
      ans_list.append(tmp) 
      print "ans_list currently: ", ans_list
      return

    j=k
    while j < len(a):
      tmp.append(a[j])
      solve(i+1,a,tmp,l,j+1)
      tmp.pop()
      j+=1


class Solution:
    # @param a : list of integers
    # @return a list of list of integers
    def subsets(self, a):
      a=sorted(a)
      global ans_list
      tmp=[]
      i=0
      for l in range(len(a)+1):
        solve(0,a,tmp,l,0)
      return ans_list

def main():
  a=[1,2,3]
  ob=Solution()
  li=ob.subsets(a)
  print "Ans:" ,li

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is the output :

```
List to append:    []
Current ans_list:  [[]]
List to append:    [1]
Current ans_list:  [[1], [1]]
List to append:    [2]
Current ans_list:  [[2], [2], [2]]
List to append:    [3]
Current ans_list:  [[3], [3], [3], [3]]
List to append:    [1, 2]
Current ans_list:  [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
List to append:    [1, 3]
Current ans_list:  [[1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3]]
List to append:    [2, 3]
Current ans_list:  [[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
List to append:    [1, 2, 3]
Current ans_list:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

Ans: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

I even tried passing `ans_list` as a parameter rather than a global variable but the result is same. Even tried to use a dictionary than a list of lists but it results in same kind of behaviour. However one interesting thing i noted is when i change `ans_list.append(tmp)` to `ans_list.extend(tmp)` in `solve` function then the output becomes :

```
List to extend:    []
Current ans_list:  []
List to extend:    [1]
Current ans_list:  [1]
List to extend:    [2]
Current ans_list:  [1, 2]
List to extend:    [3]
Current ans_list:  [1, 2, 3]
List to extend:    [1, 2]
Current ans_list:  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
List to extend:    [1, 3]
Current ans_list:  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3]
List to extend:    [2, 3]
Current ans_list:  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3]
List to extend:    [1, 2, 3]
Current ans_list:  [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

Ans: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

which is pretty much expected. Now I am not sure what is the reason for this unexpected behaviour with appending lists and dictionary in python whereas extend gives the correct response. Any help would be appreciated.

I am a newbie to python and using Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you create **tmp** outside your loop in **subsets()**. Now every usage of **tmp** in **solve()** will point to the same list and every action will be performed on every element in ans_list, including pop().

There are a lot of ways to fix this, but if you want minimal code change just import **copy** module and change:

```
ans_list.append(tmp)
```

to:

```
ans_list.append(copy.deepcopy(tmp))
```

edit (my solution):

```
ans = set()
for i in range(len(a)+1):
    for j in range(len(a)+1):
        ans.add(tuple(a[i:j]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It solved my problem. Could you link a help for other such ways which could be used to fixed this.

Comment: Rather than fixing it, I think you should re-design your solution. This problem can be solved in 5-6 pythonic line. I can publish my solution for the problem if you want

Comment: This was my 3rd code in python. I'll try to redesign it and also would love to see yours and i was curious to know about other ways which could have fixed the problem just to expand my knowledge.

Comment: (Sorry for the late response) I'm not a python expert, and I'm sure there is a one-liner that will kill this. Anyway I edited my answer to contain my solution.